# How can I open up the console in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

I'd like to know how to open the console in XCOM 2 so I can add resources to my inventory on a casual playthrough.

I can't seem to find a keybinding for it in the options menu, and in the game options.

How do I open up the console in XCOM 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open up the console by right-clicking the game in your Steam Library, click "Set Launch Options", and adding in the following:

```
-allowconsole
```

And this will allow you to open up the console any time in game.

The default console key is the tilde: <kbd>~</kbd>

Comment: Tried this with no luck ... but I've just installed the game (10th August 2016) so has it been disabled?